# SQL Array and session variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, postgresql, session-variables

I have an array in a PostGreSQL query and I can't turn it into a session variable.

The table resulting from the query sends this: `{1,2,3}`

if I transform this into a session variable I have the same thing.

If in my query, I transform my array into a string, my session variable is: `['1','2','3']`

When I use this session variable in javascript code and want to generate strings from it, it returns this: (sess_modules is my session variable)

```
for (i=0; i<sess_modules.length; i++) {
    var module = `<div class="leaflet-sidebar-pane" id="module_${i+1}"></div>`
    liste_modules.push(module);

    $("#mydiv").html("${liste_modules}")
}
```

That's works but I have commas (cf picture). Why ?

I would like to know why my code returns commas too.

HTML code:

[image]

Comment: Assuming you are using a string template, not the literal string `"${liste_modules}"`  -> `\`${liste_modules}\`` - when you *coerce* from an array to a string without specifying how-to, js will output that array with commas.     See this with: `var x = [1,2,3]; console.log("" + x)`

Comment: @freedomn-m : How can I change this ? Thks

Comment: Your issue is that you are outputting the array for *every* iteration.  Change `$("#mydiv").html("${liste_modules}")` to `$("#mydiv").append(module)` and remove `list_moduiles`

Comment: Or move the `.html(..)` line outside the loop and use  `$("#mydiv").html(liste_modules.join(""))` to join without a comma

Comment: That works. I used the first code. Thank you for your help. have a nice day. Sylvain